# How to stop the mouse click event editing the selected node of a Jtree

Tags: java, swing, jtree

I have a JTree with three level. second level nodes can be renamed on selecting an option in a menu. Even when I clicked rename option in the menu, still I need to double click the node to edit it. I want to stop the mouse click event to edit it and let the user edit the node only by selecting the menu item. Since I'm new to Swing I may have missed something in my code. Please help to proceed. Below is my code.

```
    JMenuItem itemRename = new JMenuItem("Rename");

itemRename.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
        DefaultMutableTreeNode selectedNode = (DefaultMutableTreeNode) 
        tree.getLastSelectedPathComponent();
        Object testCaseNodeInfo=selectedNode.getUserObject();
        String oldName=(String)testCaseNodeInfo;
        tree.setEditable(true);

        DefaultTreeCellEditor editor=new DefaultTreeCellEditor(tree,
                (DefaultTreeCellRenderer)tree.getCellRenderer()){
            @Override
            public boolean isCellEditable(EventObject event) {
                if(event instanceof MouseEvent){
                    return false;
                }
                return super.isCellEditable(event);
            }
        };
        tree.setCellEditor(editor);

/*this allows to save the changed item in a global object on pressing 
Enter key after the change */                   
tree.getModel().addTreeModelListener(new TCTreeModeListener(oldName));

    }
});

add(itemRename);
```

Answer (score 0):

I have added the following code when action performed and it helped to stop editing the node by double clicking allow editing when selected the menu item.

```
 TreePath selectionPath = tree.getSelectionPath();
 tree.startEditingAtPath(selectionPath);
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [`TreeCellEditor#isCelLEditable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/CellEditor.html#isCellEditable-java.util.EventObject-), this is what is used by the `JTree` to determine if a cell should start editing or not